# When a file is missing from the source location, the lftp mv command takes a while. How may this unnecessary delay be avoided?

Tags: shell, unix, ftp, sftp, lftp

```
lftp SPORT -u ${SPID}, ${ServerURL} -e "set ssl:cert-file $SPID_CERT; set sslkey-file $SPID_CERT_KEY;
cd /G/reg_service/
mv file1.txt file2.txt /G/reg_service/2023/OTC/
bye:"
```

When `file1.txt` or `file2.txt` are absent, the command is waiting for a long time. How can you stop this?

If the file is missing, I expect the `lftp` command to end immediately.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.